# What is a good starter set or in general, items to have for a DND campaign?

Tags: dnd-5e, new-players

I’m asking this so I can start a dnd session with some friends of mine, I already have the Mines of Phandelver starter pack with the character sheets and lore of the story, it there anything else I should get?

Comment: @NautArch Yea, I do have fifth edition, also thank you Thomas for giving me the link

Comment: The linked question should cover what you need here, so we've closed this as a duplicate. *This is okay!* Duplicate questions can help users find what they're looking for, I know I usually have an issue finding the linked question.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.